# In Regicide, how do you become the king?

Tags: halo-4

I've played several rounds of Regicide, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to become the king.  Occasionally I get it, but it doesn't seem tied to me killing the king, which happens constantly.  What's the deal - how do I become king?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person with the highest score at any given time is the king. In the case of a tie the current king stays the king.

Answer (score 1):

You are the king when you have the highest score. I'm not exactly sure what happens when there is a tie, but I think you have to *pass* the king to become the king.